# How to make -AccessTokens work with Connect-MicrosoftTeams cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

I am following this link to connect to Microsoft Teams using Access Tokens:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/teams-powershell-application-authentication

Here is the code:

```
$ClientSecret   = 'xxxxx~xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
$ApplicationID = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
$TenantID = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    
$graphtokenBody = @{   
   Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"   
   Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"   
   Client_Id     = $ApplicationID   
   Client_Secret = $ClientSecret   
}  
    
$graphToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $graphtokenBody | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access_Token 
    
$teamstokenBody = @{   
   Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"   
   Scope         = "48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239/.default"   
   Client_Id     = $ApplicationID   
   Client_Secret = $ClientSecret 
} 
    
$teamsToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $teamstokenBody | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access_Token 
    
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @("$graphToken", "$teamsToken")
```

The application is registered in Azure AD and has been assigned the API permissions as mentioned in the article. I have assigned Teams administrator role to the application as well. Tokens get populated correctly.

Running the code produces the following error:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:29 char:1
+ Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @("$graphToken", "$teamsToken")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-MicrosoftTeams], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-MicrosoftTeams,Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.Powershell.Connect.ConnectMicrosoftTeams
 
Connect-MicrosoftTeams : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:29 char:1
+ Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @("$graphToken", "$teamsToken")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-MicrosoftTeams], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.Powershell.Connect.ConnectMicrosoftTeams
```

If someone had this issue and have successfully resolved it or have some tips on how to resolve it, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the version of Microsoft teams you are trying to connect is older than **`4.7.1-preview`** version.

**To resolve the error**, try updating the Microsoft teams PowerShell version to **`4.7.1-preview`** or later and this type of authentication is supported only in commercial environments.

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name MicrosoftTeams
Update-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams
```

[image]

After updating the PowerShell Module, ***I am able to connect to Microsoft Teams successfully*** like below:

```
$ClientSecret   = "ClientSecret"
$ApplicationID = "AppID"
$TenantID = "TenantID"

$graphtokenBody = @{   
   Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"   
   Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"   
   Client_Id     = $ApplicationID   
   Client_Secret = $ClientSecret   
}  

$graphToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $graphtokenBody | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access_Token 

$teamstokenBody = @{   
   Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"   
   Scope         = "48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239/.default"   
   Client_Id     = $ApplicationID   
   Client_Secret = $ClientSecret 
} 

$teamsToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $teamstokenBody | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access_Token 

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @("$graphToken", "$teamsToken")
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[PowerShell Gallery | MicrosoftTeams 4.9.1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftTeams/4.9.1)

Comment: Your answer led me to the right direction to resolve the issue. In my case, it was not about installing the new version of MicrosoftTeams module which I already had on my machine (version 4.9.1) . I noticed that the older versions of Teams module 4.3 and 4.6 were still hanging around from the earlier installations. Removing those older versions did the trick. Thanks.